# How to disapper the images once the page is loaded using css

Tags: css

Can any one help me how to disappear the images automatically once the page is loaded using css.

Comment: You can not disappear the images automatically using css you can do using javascript

Comment: webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {   opacity: 1;    }
    99% {       opacity: 0;    }
    100% {        display: hide;     }
}
keyframes fadeOut {    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        display: hide;
    }
}
.imageClass {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;        
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    animation: fadeOut 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

Comment: I used this css to disappear the images but after a few seconds the images are again visible but i dont want the images to be visible can any one help me.

Comment: through css cant we disappear the images

Comment: Yes but  the page load complete action will not fire using css you need add js when page loading complete it will add class to image to hide the images

Comment: Can u send me once the process

Comment: can any one help me please

Comment: Yes  can you please add css and html so i will add JS

Comment: css which i added it is wrong aa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92689/discussion-between-mitul-and-user2630366).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.everine-affilate-no-image').fadeOut('1000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='everine-affilate-no-image' src="http://www.washingtonbeerblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/crash_test1.jpg">
<img src="http://shirtoid.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/you-big-dummy.jpg">
<img class='everine-affilate-no-image' src="http://prevenblog.com/wp-content/uploads/Dummy.jpg">
<img src="http://uvamagazine.org/images/uploads/2009/0901/0901_RD_dummy.jpg">
```

Comment: <div class="everine-affilate-image-holder">
<img class="everine-affilate-no-image" src="<?php echo EVERINE_PLUGIN_DIR_URL . '/assets/img/no_pict2.png'; ?>">
<?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($item['image-id'], 'medium'); ?>
<img class="everine-affilate-image" src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" style="<?php echo ($sub_total == 0)? 'display: none;' : ''; ?>" >
</div> This is code which we are using for getting the images

Comment: Ok so you are adding `everine-affilate-no-image` class to all images which you want to hide right?

Comment: We will use everine-affilate-image to show the image but it should disapper the image and that image will be everine-affilate-no-image

Comment: OK i have changed code which will hide all the images which have `everine-affilate-no-image` class

Comment: Why what is the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92694/discussion-between-user2630366-and-mitul).

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
//alert("hi");
    setTimeout(function() { 
 //alert("hi");
        jQuery('.everine-affilate-image').hide('fast'); 
  
     }, 10000); 
});   As we used this code for hiding all the images at a time when i login in the same way i need if i accept one gift i will get one image and that time also that one image should be disappeared

Comment: can any one help me regarding this

Comment: I code which i copied it is hiding all the images at a time nut what i need is if iam accepting any gift then i will get one image at that time also the image should be hided.